# How to mock toJSON() function in JEST?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing my React application using JEST and React Testing Library but I have encountered an error. The test fails on **timeEndRow.toJSON()** stating that timeEndRow.toJSON() is not a function.

```js
if (timeEndRow && !equalityChecker(timeEndRow && timeEndRow.toJSON(), timeLastRow && timeLastRow.toJSON()) && !longSession) {
    // some code      
};
```

Comment: What _is_ `timeEndRow`?

Comment: It's a DOMRect Object 
const timeEndRow = timeRowEndEle ? timeRowEndEle.getBoundingClientRect() : null;

Comment: I think you're looking for [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), eg. `JSON.stringify(timeEndRow)`

Comment: Actually toJSON() directly returns parsed Object whereas JSON.stringify() will return unparsed object. Isn't there any way that I can mock the toJSON()?

Comment: I would suggest _not_ mocking it, but it's unclear what exactly the context is.

Comment: @PasanSumanaratne I Have already mentioned it. It's a DOMRect Object

Comment: At the time of this line executing in your code when running the test, is it still a DOMRect object or is it null, since you have a condition here at const timeEndRow = timeRowEndEle ? timeRowEndEle.getBoundingClientRect() : null;